# Using htmlspecialchars on a URL

Tags: php, url, encoding, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I have URLs in this format :

> http://site.com/index.php?title=[SOME_UNICODE_TITLE]&id=[ID]&type=[TYPE]

When I try to use `htmlspecialchars` on this URL to encode unicode title the function encodes `&` too; so it will be `&amp` so variable name `id` is converted to `ampid` !
So I can't read it from code.

How can I use `htmlspecialchars` on a URL without converting URL specific chars (e.g. `&`,`=`,...)?

Comment: what about [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Well yes, that's what `htmlspecialchars` does. What is the use case? What do you want to escape it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO you should just use `urlencode()` for URLs, because that's what it is made for. If you cannot / do not want to use it and you always get a full URI. You could parse if before encoding it:

```
$uriParts = parse_url($fullUri);
$queryParts = array();
parse_str($uriParts['query'], $queryParts);

foreach($queryParts as $name => $value) {
    $queryParts[$name] = htmlspecialchars($value);

    // don't know whether you want to encode the key too
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lIFiHB

Answer (score 0):

if u wana just encode the data, rather than appying htmlspecialchars to whole of the url, will recommend applying it exclusively to the content only. This way u will conserve the url with the special charecters in the data

Comment: I'm using someone else's class that returns the entire URL and not it's parts! I only have the entire URL.